# Email js validator dont work correctly

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I have a website: http://www.admiraltax.pl/zamow_darmowa_konsultacje

I tried to validate js e-mail address that could give 5 characters after the dot, eg. D4rqu@testowy.EMAIL.

Validator worked for me only max 4 characters,

I changed main.js, but it doesn't work :(

```
validEmail function (e-mail)
{
             var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0- 9] {2,6}) + $ /;
             if (filter.test (e-mail))
                 return true;
             else
                 return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: `validEmail function (e-mail)` -> `function validEmail(email)`

Comment: and delete whitespaces in regex

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something a bit more simple works ?

```
/.+@.+/
```

or you could try this:

```
\^([\w]+)\@([\w]+){5}\.([\w]+)$\
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not js, i correct form.php:

```
public function is_email($name) {

    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->post) === false)
        return false;

    if (!is_string($this->post[$name]))
        return false;


    $email = $this->post[$name];
    $reg   = '#^(([[:alnum:]]|[\_\.\-])+@[[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]]|[\_\.\-])*\.([[:alpha:]]){2,6})$#si';

    if (!preg_match($reg, $email))
        return false;

    return true;
    }
```

And now its work